# Why do I get a return of bool(false) disable me?

Tags: php, wordpress, boolean

Can you please help get this file to run without returning bool(false) disable me!.

Here is the file:

```
<?php
$user_id = jmdougla; # Insert your user ID or simply 1 for the first user that was     created
$user_pass = 'jt620600'; # Insert a new password
$ip = '108.214.33.88'; # Insert your IP

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === $ip) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
    $user = wp_update_user(array(
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'user_pass' => $user_pass,
    )) ;
    var_dump(get_userdata($user));
    die('disable me!'); 
}
```

I'm trying to reset my password in a wordpress blog.

Thanks for any help youu can provide.

Comment: Do you mean that get_userdata() is returning false? That may mean that $user isn't a valid user, i.e. your wp_update_user() failed. You should var_dump the return from that (i.e. `var_dump($user)`) to see if you're getting a WP_Error object back. If you are, that object will have more information on what went wrong.

Comment: (Also: don't you have access to the database? Why not just [reset it in there](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password#Through_phpMyAdmin)?)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove (or comment out) the `die('disable me!');` statement.